# Undefined method each in Ruby Regexp task

Tags: ruby, regex, file, grep

I have series of zip files under `@workingdir`, and am trying to unzip the files that match `@Regexp`, and print the lines from them.

```
require 'zip/zip'
@workingdir = '/my/dir/structure/*.zip'
@Regexp = '/yup:maybe.*nope/i'

Dir.glob(@workingdir) do |zips|
    Zip::ZipFile.open(zips) do |file|
        file.each do |search|
            tempFile = file.read(search)
            tempFile.each do |line|
                if (line =~ @Regexp ) then
                p line
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Below is the error message from IRB:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<String:0x0000000168bf40>
from (irb):70:in `block (3 levels) in irb_binding'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubyzip2-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1122:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubyzip2-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1122:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubyzip2-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1265:in `each'
from (irb):68:in `block (2 levels) in irb_binding'
from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rubyzip2-2.0.2/lib/zip/zip.rb:1381:in `open'
from (irb):67:in `block in irb_binding'
from (irb):66:in `glob'
from (irb):66
from /usr/bin/irb:12:in `<main>'
```

I tried `tempFile.grep`, and received the same error, except that `grep` was an undefined method. I believe I need to define a class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out my code had two problems. 1) My regular expression was being processed as a string (I should not have used the quotes). 2) Seeing as it runs fine otherwise on Ruby 1.8.7, I suspect the is a difference in how 1.8.7 and 1.9.1 process the 'each' method. If anyone has additional insights, I'm more than happy to hear them. The code below works fine on 1.8.7:

```
require 'zip/zip'
@workingdir = '/my/dir/structure/*.zip'
@Regexp = /regexp/i

Dir.glob(@workingdir) do |zips|
    Zip::ZipFile.open(zips) do |file|
        file.each do |search|
            tempFile = file.read(search)
            tempFile.each do |line|
                if (line =~ @Regexp) then
        puts zips + ': ' + line.chomp
                end
            end
        end
    end
end
```

Thanks again everyone!